# pthread_create segmentation fault with pthread_create.c 552

Tags: c, multithreading

I am getting a segmentation fault right after I am creating a thread. The thread that I am creating is globally defined list. [gdb description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk7VN.png)[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpPSg.png) Stdout does not print the print statement right after pthread_create. Would appreciate any help

Comment: can you edit question with code snippet ? what you doing ? like 
[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages now, especially the latter.  We'll need an MCVE ([MCVE]) included in the question; sending us to somewhere offsite in an image isn't OK — we can't copy the code and experiment with it, all else apart.

Comment: `t1` is probably `NULL` [or points to random memory] on your _first_ `pthread_create` call, as it is the only value you pass in that _could_ cause a segfault, but it's difficult to know without the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. Will be better in the future. @CraigEstey You were right. I forgot to malloc what t1 was equal to. Thank you for pointing this out!